# Display mutiple images rendering BLOB from mysql in img tag

Tags: php, mysql, image, binary, blob

I converted images in Binary and saved them in BLOB format in Mysql Database.
Now, i'm trying to display all that images of different MIME types. 
I have tried many times with different suggestions (stackoverflow) and searched over other webs also. But, Still unable to display images.

For this i used LAMP server with Core PHP (PHP 7.1) & MySql 5.6 as Database. 
To convert images into Binary:

```
function data_uri($file, $mime) 
{  
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
```

To store this binary in DB:

```
$filename=array("file.jpg","file 22.png","file 11.png","file 1.jpg");
foreach ($filename as $value) {  
$pos = strrpos($value, '.');
$extensions= substr($value, $pos+1);   
if($extensions=='jpg'){
$ext='image/jpg';
$imageData= data_uri('./downloads/'.$value,$ext);
}
if($extensions=='png'){
$ext='image/png'; 
$imageData= data_uri('./downloads/'.$value,$ext);            
}
$sql1="INSERT INTO image(name,binary_image,extension) 
VALUES('".$value."','".$imageData."','".$ext."') ";
$rt=$conn->query($sql1);          
}
```

To Access data from database in show images over screen:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM image";
$res=$conn->query($sql);
if($res->num_rows >0){
while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
$filenam= $row['name'];
$binaryData= explode(',',$row['binary_image']);
$extens= $row['extension'];
//echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$binaryData[1].'" alt="photo"> 
<br>';
?>
<img src="<?=$binaryData[0].','. $binaryData[1] ?>" />
<?php  }
}
```

Corrupted images with binary data

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop for each image :

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM image";
$res=$conn->query($sql);
if($res->num_rows >0){
while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){

    $filenam= $row['name'];
    $binaryData= explode(',',$row['binary_image']);
    $extens= $row['extension'];


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($binaryData); $i++){
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$binaryData[$i].'" alt="photo"><br>';
    }



    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Here we using `strlen($binaryData);` then length of string is about 65513.  Sorry to say but i didn't get your answer.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, change with count()

Comment: but after using `explode` --> `$binaryData` we received array with 2 elements. So, the `count` of `$binaryData` is 2 and `[1]=>'data:image/jpeg;base64,data:image/jpg;base64'`, `[2]=>'BOLB value'`

Comment: oh maybe i misunderstood something, i thought you explode $row['binary_image'] because you had more than 1 image on this row field data. if not you do not need to add the loop

Comment: yeah that's what i'm talking. thanks for suggestions & response. :)